# loading files using JLD2 in julia when they're saved with commas

Tags: io, julia

I have saved my data in julia using the command below

`JLD2.@save "myfile.jld2" a, b, c`

and I understand I should have used

`JLD2.@save "myfile.jld2" a b c`.

Is there still any way to access the data in `myfile.jld2` file. Right now, if I run

`JLD2.@load "myfile.jld2"`

I get

```
1-element Array{Symbol,1}:
 Symbol("(a, b, c)")
```

and not a, b, c data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can - just use `"a, b, c"` as the data identifier.

Setup:

```
using JLD2
a,b,c = 255,"some nice text",6666.0
JLD2.@save "file.jld2" a, b, c
```

Identifying and reading the data:

```
julia> f=jldopen("file.jld2","r")
JLDFile C:\Users\pszufe\file.jld2 (read-only)
 └─� (a, b, c)

julia> keys(f)
1-element Array{String,1}:
 "(a, b, c)"

julia> read(f,keys(f)[1])
(255, "some nice text", 6666.0)
```